# "IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error" when calling python-program from haskell System.Process

Tags: python, haskell, terminal

the following script runs perfectly if I manually run it from terminal.

```
import sys
import pygame
import pygame.mixer

def play(path):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(path)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

while True:
    path = sys.stdin.readline()[0:-1]
    play(path)
```

whenever I type a path it starts playing that file (and stops playing the previous).

but when i call it from this haskell script:

```
import System.Process
import GHC.IO.Handle

main = do
    (Just input, _, _, _) <- createProcess (proc "python" ["mplayer.py"])
    hPutStr input "song.mp3\n"
```

I get the following error-message:

```
Main: user error (Pattern match failure in do expression at     Main.hs:6:9-29)
gernot@gernot-Aspire-5733Z:~/Dokumente/Projekte/python/music$ Traceback     (most recent call last):
  File "mplayer.py", line 14, in <module>
    path = sys.stdin.readline()[0:-1]
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

I googled the error-message and didn’t find anything useful for either python or haskell. 
anyway, the error persists if I append some busy-waiting to the haskell-script

Comment: sounds that haskell script has run the process with stdin closed. Can't you pass the info as command line parameter instead? (using `sys.argv[1]`). that would solve that.

Comment: afaik sys.argv[1] only works if I never want to send new input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the process' stdin to be a pipe, you have to explicitly request it:

```
(Just input, _, _, _) <- createProcess ((proc "python" ["mplayer.py"]) { std_in = CreatePipe })
```

Quoting [the fine documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.4.3.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:createProcess):

> `createProcess` returns `(`*mb_stdin_hdl*`,` *mb_stdout_hdl*`,` *mb_stderr_hdl*`,` *ph*`)`, where
>
> - if `std_in == CreatePipe`, then *mb_stdin_hdl* will be `Just` *h*, where *h* is the write end of the pipe connected to the child process's `stdin`.
> - otherwise, *mb_stdin_hdl* `== Nothing`
>
> Similarly for *mb_stdout_hdl* and *mb_stderr_hdl*.

Comment: doesn’t crash now. but input is still not bound to sys.stdin.readline()

Comment: @someidiot You can use `hPutStrLn input "song.mp3"` instead of `putStr input "song.mp3\n" >> hFlush input` (unless you have changed `input` to block buffering).